# Get Value from Map column with default

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, dictionary

Currently I use `df.withColumn("col", col("mapColumn").getItem("key"))`but this gives me `null` value if the key is not present in the map column. Is there anything equivalent to `getOrElse("key", defaultCalue)` in Spark/Scala ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`coalesce`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@coalesce(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column*):org.apache.spark.sql.Column), as shown below:

```
val df = Seq(
  (10, Map(1 -> "a", 2 -> "b")),
  (20, Map(3 -> "c"))
).toDF("idCol", "mapCol")

df.withColumn("mapValOf1", coalesce($"mapCol"(1), lit("unknown"))).show
// +-----+----------------+---------+
// |idCol|          mapCol|mapValOf1|
// +-----+----------------+---------+
// |   10|[1 -> a, 2 -> b]|        a|
// |   20|        [3 -> c]|  unknown|
// +-----+----------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1):

use `when` clause.
something like

```
df.withColumn("col", when(col("mapColumn").getItem("key").isNotNull,col("mapColumn").getItem("key")).otherwise(lit("DEFAULT_VALUE")))
```